Trying to find the name of a science fiction movie from the 1950's or 1960's
I saw this movie on TV in the late 60's. I think it was a black and white not color. It was probably made in the late 50's or early 60's. It was science fiction and involved two scientists and a woman. 
The scientists found an opening in the earth that led to a big cavern below. On the cavern floor were two openings opposite each other. To explore the cavern one scientist was lowered by some kind of platform into the cavern, but the platform broke down and left the scientist hovering above the cavern floor. Things came into the cavern through the openings to threaten the scientist but the platform was out of their reach. I think one of the things was a giant spider and at the end of the movie two dinosaurs were fighting beneath him. 
I highly doubt that anybody knows this movie but I would appreciate any thoughts or suggestions.

A quick Google search ("1950's movie cavern beneath the earth") returned The Spider from 1958. It's got a giant underground cavern and a giant spider. 
 Here's the trailer:



